# If a zombie seen a mirror, would it attack the mirror due to the reflection?

Tags: zombie

I have thought about building a wall with two-way mirrors in certain spots so that I could see any and all activity around my base. I was wondering if, given what is known about typical zombie behavior, would they attack their own reflection?

Of course this is all fictional, just a fun thought experiment.

For this purpose, I assume the most likely type of zombie, Solanum the virus. (http://zombie.wikia.com/wiki/Solanum)

Comment: I would suggest making this specific to *World War Z*, as there are many different zombie portrayals in both film and literature. The Solanum idea is relatively new, but there is no reason to believe it applies outside of Max Brooks' work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems very improbable for a few reasons:

- They don't attack each other, so why would one attack an image of itself?
- Some of them, especially obvious with The Walking Dead, rely (at least partially) on the smell of the living to attack.
- Zombies in other movies (including the original Dawn of the Dead) encounter windows quite often and don't seem to notice their reflections. Maybe it's deep-rooted enough like the concepts of walking, doors, windows, etc, that zombies seem to understand enough when they encounter them.

Another thing to consider is that for two way mirrors to work, you'd need to have the lights out on your side of the glass or else the zombies could see through them. On moonless nights, when it's pitch black outside, I'd rather be behind some wood or steel rather than a sheet of glass. Doubly so during strong winds or hail storms.

I'd advise against it. Maybe just replace *existing* windows with 2-way mirrors so you can still shutter or board them up.

Comment: Would you like one way mirrors that take sledgehammers to break?